# How to properly set a break point in bochs

Tags: assembly, nasm, bochs

I want to use bochs to debug a mini os which is written in nasm assembly. I expect to find an instruction to set a breakpoint at a certain line in source code. However from the document here: http://bochs.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/topper.pl?name=New+Bochs+Documentation&url=http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook You can only set a breakpoint at a certain physical address, virtual address or linear address. How can I know what address corresponds to a certain line in source code?

Comment: You need to extract that information from your build toolchain (such as objdump or an assembly listing file), and of course you need knowledge of your own loader (where it loads stuff).

Comment: If you know where you want to set the breakpoint, and your os is compiled to Intel assembly, you can insert a `0xcc` aka `int 3` instruction in your os's source (and recompile it) to trigger a debugger interrupt.

Comment: Building on @Kenney's comment above, [bochs supports magic breakpoints](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bochs#Magic_Breakpoint) (`xchg bx, bx`) since `int3` normally stays inside the virtual machine and does not break out to the bochs debugger.

Comment: What environment are you on, and I am curious do you have the ability to compile Bochs with gdbstub support? I don't know about the internal Bochs debugger, but I have successfully used gdb using a remote session to Bochs to set breakpoints using symbolic debugging information in ELF32 format binaries (nasm can produce such information). Is your OS 16-bit or 32-bit code?

Comment: @MichaelPetch It is 32 bit kubuntu running on Armv7l. It is a chromebook running kubuntu. I never tried to compile with gdbstub but bochs is said to be platform independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out if compile bochs with --enable-disasm then I can use command 'u' to disassemble code when debugging.